# Employee Pay program in C, with arrays and structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm having some issues with the output of this program.

The logic seems to be okay, but whenever I compile/run it I get an (11db) in the output section (I use Xcode).

It says "build succeeded" and doesn't show any errors in the code itself.

Basically, you have to read in some values from an input file "clock.txt", which contains:

*the # of employees (n) *their first and last names, followed by their rate of pay, (you put it into a struct called employee) *the #of weeks (k)

You then have to calculate the gross pay for the week (over, the total amount of taxes, and the net pay (gross - taxes).

Here's what I have written thus far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LEN 30

struct employee {
    char first[MAX_LEN];
    char last[MAX_LEN];
    double payperhr;
    double gross;
    double taxes;
    double hours_in_week;
} ;

int main() {
    FILE *ifp, *ofp;
    ifp = fopen("clock.txt", "r");
    ofp = fopen("w2.txt", "w");
    int i, j, n, k, m, l, matchLast, found;
    int hourIn, minIn, hourOut, minOut;
    double total_time_day = 0.0;
    double under40tax, over40tax, tax;
    double netPay;

    char  firstRead[MAX_LEN],  lastRead[MAX_LEN], lastName[MAX_LEN], firstName[MAX_LEN];
    float rateRead;

    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &n);


    struct employee arrayEmployees[n];

    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        fscanf(ifp, "%s", firstRead);
        fscanf(ifp, "%s", lastRead);
        fscanf(ifp, "%f", &rateRead);

        strcpy(arrayEmployees[n].first, firstRead);
        strcpy(arrayEmployees[n].last, lastRead);
        arrayEmployees[n].payperhr = rateRead;
    }

    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &k);
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &m);

    for (i=0; i<k; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<m; j++) {
            fscanf(ifp, "%s", lastName);
            fscanf(ifp, "%s", firstName);

            for (l=0; l<n; l++)
                matchLast = strcmp(lastName, arrayEmployees[l].last);
            if (matchLast == 0) {
                found = matchLast;
                strcpy(arrayEmployees[i].last, lastName);
                strcpy(arrayEmployees[i].first, firstName);

                fscanf(ifp, "%d%d%d%d", &hourIn, &minIn, &hourOut, &minOut);
                hourIn%=12;
                hourOut%=12;
                total_time_day = (((hourOut*1.0) - hourIn)+((minOut*1.0) - minIn))/60;
                arrayEmployees[j].hours_in_week += total_time_day;
                arrayEmployees[j].gross += total_time_day*rateRead;
            }
        }
        if (arrayEmployees[i].hours_in_week/40<1) {
            under40tax = arrayEmployees[j].gross*.1;
            tax = under40tax;
            arrayEmployees[i].taxes = tax;
        }
        else if (arrayEmployees[j].hours_in_week/40>1) {
            over40tax = (40*.1)+((arrayEmployees[j].hours_in_week-40)*.2);
            arrayEmployees[i].gross -= 40;
            arrayEmployees[i].gross = arrayEmployees[i].hours_in_week*1.5;
            arrayEmployees[i].gross +=40;
            tax = over40tax;
            arrayEmployees[i].taxes = tax;
        }
        netPay = arrayEmployees[i].gross - tax;
        arrayEmployees[i].hours_in_week = 0.0;

        fprintf(ofp, "W2 Form\n");
        fprintf(ofp, "-----");
        fprintf(ofp, "Name: %s %s", arrayEmployees[i].last, arrayEmployees[i].first);
        fprintf(ofp, "Gross Pay:  %lf", arrayEmployees[i].gross);
        fprintf(ofp, "Taxes Withheld:  %lf", arrayEmployees[i].taxes);
        fprintf(ofp, "Net Pay:  %lf", netPay);

        arrayEmployees[i].hours_in_week = 0.0;
        arrayEmployees[i].taxes = 0.0;
        arrayEmployees[i].gross = 0.0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: n is not constant at compile time, how can  struct employee arrayEmployees[n]; compiles?

Comment: @tacp That is still legal `C99`. It is a variable length array.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant `arrayEmployees[i]` rather than `arrayEmployees[n]` in the first `for` loop in `main`. You are also never checking whether `ifp` and `ofp` are NULL.

Comment: In your for loop, strcpy(arrayEmployees[n].first, firstRead);
        strcpy(arrayEmployees[n].last, lastRead);
        arrayEmployees[n].payperhr = rateRead; Why did you put [n] ? It should be [i].

Comment: I believe VLA's have been changed to "optional" in C11, so be wary of using them without at least thinking about portability issues.  Of course, this one reeks of homework, so that's probably not a concern.

Comment: Anish, where would be the optimal places to check if ifp/ofp are NULL?

Comment: Randy, what is a VLA?

Comment: @user2044189, Right after you call `fopen` for each of them! Also, whenever you're [replying to a comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-reply), please use the '@' symbol, _immediately_ followed by the name, followed by a space.

Comment: Program seems to be ok. what is the actual output you are getting Can we see a sample input and output so we can understand your requirement s a bit better?

Comment: @nimish the thing is, the output is only the characters "(11db)".  That is all I get as the output.  I have tried removing all of the "file" related machanisms in the problem (replacing fscanf/fprintf with scant and printf, etc.) and it actually did give me an output, with the correct printed statements, but the values of the variables I print at the end were each about 10 digits of gibberish.  I suspect that I might need to insert a pointer/asterisk somewhere but I don't know exactly where to put it.

Comment: @AnishRam I have inserted those calls but the output has not changed.

Comment: @user2044189, What calls are you talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem here

```
 for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    fscanf(ifp, "%s", firstRead);
    fscanf(ifp, "%s", lastRead);
    fscanf(ifp, "%f", &rateRead);

    strcpy(arrayEmployees[n].first, firstRead);
    strcpy(arrayEmployees[n].last, lastRead);
    arrayEmployees[n].payperhr = rateRead;
}
```

and

```
    for (j=0; j<m; j++) {
        fscanf(ifp, "%s", lastName);
        fscanf(ifp, "%s", firstName);

        for (l=0; l<n; l++)
            matchLast = strcmp(lastName, arrayEmployees[l].last);
        if (matchLast == 0) {
            found = matchLast;
            strcpy(arrayEmployees[i].last, lastName);
            strcpy(arrayEmployees[i].first, firstName);

            fscanf(ifp, "%d%d%d%d", &hourIn, &minIn, &hourOut, &minOut);
            hourIn%=12;
            hourOut%=12;
            total_time_day = (((hourOut*1.0) - hourIn)+((minOut*1.0) - minIn))/60;
            arrayEmployees[j].hours_in_week += total_time_day;
            arrayEmployees[j].gross += total_time_day*rateRead;
        }
    }
```

it should actually be

```
 for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    fscanf(ifp, "%s", firstRead);
    fscanf(ifp, "%s", lastRead);
    fscanf(ifp, "%f", &rateRead);

    strcpy(arrayEmployees[i].first, firstRead);
    strcpy(arrayEmployees[i].last, lastRead);
    arrayEmployees[i].payperhr = rateRead;
}
```

and

```
    for (j=0; j<m; j++) {

        fscanf(ifp, "%s", lastName);
        fscanf(ifp, "%s", firstName);

        for (l=0; l<n; l++){

            matchLast = strcmp(lastName, arrayEmployees[l].last);

            if (matchLast == 0) {

                found = matchLast;
                strcpy(arrayEmployees[j].last, lastName);
                strcpy(arrayEmployees[j].first, firstName);

                fscanf(ifp, "%d%d%d%d", &hourIn, &minIn, &hourOut, &minOut);

                hourIn%=12;
                hourOut%=12;
                total_time_day = (((hourOut*1.0) - hourIn)+((minOut*1.0) - minIn))/60;

                arrayEmployees[j].hours_in_week += total_time_day;
                arrayEmployees[j].gross += total_time_day*rateRead;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I fixed this issue, but it still didn't compile, so I inserted an if statement to check for NULL and it went through.  So the file isn't even opening.  How do you fix a file that won't be read?

Comment: @user2044189 Without the input and the output i am unable to figure out whats k and m but i think seeing the code i feel my modified answer should be all what you need